# Protect against SQL Injection - test with sqlmap

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

i wish to know if i need protection against sql injection only in the case of the inserts i write, or if it is needed to use prepared statements for all the queries. How do i test it with sqlmap? (localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Use Prepared statements below is an example

```
$name = $_GET['username'];
```

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password FROM tbl_users WHERE name=?")) {

```
// Bind a variable to the parameter as a string. 
$stmt->bind_param("s", $name);

// Execute the statement.
$stmt->execute();

// Get the variables from the query.
$stmt->bind_result($pass);

// Fetch the data.
$stmt->fetch();

// Display the data.
printf("Password for user %s is %s\n", $name, $pass);

// Close the prepared statement.
$stmt->close();
```

}

Comment: Refer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: i know how to use prepared statements...i don t know if i have to do it for all querries

Comment: If you restrict the user at the time of login then that is well enough.